# Why does Dr. Strange have such a high collar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

In the original comics and in the newly released photos of Benedict Cumberbatch from the movie version, Dr. Strange wears an outfit with an excessively high collar. Does this high collar have a purpose and, if so, what is it?

[image]

Comment: That collar, along with the red cape, is actually an artifact called The Cloak of Levitation. Besides, big collars always come back into style eventually.

Comment: Because high collars are cool

Comment: Good to see we’re really getting to the key points of this movie, and even well before it’s released.

Comment: Hey, it gets windy on the Astral Plane.

Comment: The purpose of high collars back in the day was to protect your neck from cold and wind, the purpose now is fashion.

Comment: Dandruff collector par excellence

Comment: @GorchestopherH: And actually, high collars were just how it was done. Collars being lowered was the radical change. :) One too many cases of someone turning their head and compressing their caratoid artery on a starched collar, I guess.

Comment: At least he only has [collar](http://www.maniacworld.com/four-popped-collars-cool.jpg)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The collar, along with the cape attached to it, is actually an arcane artifact - one that responds to the mind of its wearer - called [**The Cloak of Levitation**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Levitation). The high collar itself does not serve a purpose, but that is indeed how the cloak was originally designed when it first appeared in Strange Tales #127 (December 1963). Even before the cape's debut, Strange wore a tunic which also had a high collar:

[image]

**Speculation:** At the time, high or "popped" collars were seen as a symbol of rebellion and "coolness" in American society. Doctor Strange has always been somewhat of an outsider in the Marvel universe, so perhaps that is what the cloak's collar was meant to convey.

**Update:** As an added bonus, there is a reference to this in the film itself...

> At the moment where Strange decides to give up his old life and embrace his new role as a sorceror, he is staring into a mirror with the collar laying nearly flat. He pops the collar up in a "Let's do this" manner before proceeding to go kick magical butt.

Comment: Answered in the classic Marvel Fashion: Nuff Said!

Comment: Admit it, it's for the hightened effect of razor cheekbones.

Comment: As a bonus, collars used to always be popped, so an upturned collar also has a bonus of looking slightly archaic, as per depictions of Dracula.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upturned_collar#Origins

Comment: There is a German saying: ,,Ist der Kragen oben, wird man Dich loben." - Is the collar up you get praise or something like that.

Comment: Notably, when Benedict Cumberbatch plays Sherlock Holmes on the BBC, he wears his coat collar this way. I thought it was a call-out to that as well.

Comment: @docwebhead I assumed the Sherlock collar is popped for practical reasons, though. Namely, having a barrier to wind and rain for the sunny London clime ;)